# How to define Drop regions over images in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, drag-and-drop

I would like to create an app with Xamarin.Forms and let users drag elements (text or images) and drop them over rectangle regions over an image.

Are there libraries that allow to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drag & Drop in Xamarin.Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47331388/drag-drop-in-xamarin-forms)

Answer (score 1):

Actually there seems to be at least one library for D'n'D `ListView`s (see [here](https://github.com/isychev93/Xamarin.Forms-Drag-and-drop-ListView)). Furthermore, the Syncfusion `GridView` seems to support D'n'D (see [here](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/sfdatagrid/columndraganddrop)).

Unfortunately (as far as I know) there is no standard way of doing this and if you need something a bit more customizable you'll have to implement this by yourself.

Just some thoughts on **how one could implement D'n'D**:

- Implement a draggable view class
- That view class will call some sort of D'n'D handler if the users taps down and moves
- the D'n'D handler will be responsible to display the contents (or some hint of the actual control) on an overlay
- you'll have to render some sort of hint on the potential target control
- you'll have to implement dropping actions when the user releases xis touch

*Maybe* it's possible to use behaviors for this.

If you'd like to do this for a *very limited scope* (a single use-case) it *may be feasible*, but a generic solution will take very much effort.